# flutter column remove children between space

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I wanted to stack multiple children together without gaps
But they add up and there's a white gap in the middle
I don't know why

this is my sample code

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title')),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 120,
                height: 50,
                color: Color(0xcc000000),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 120,
                height: 50,
                color: Color(0xcc000000),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 120,
                height: 50,
                color: Color(0xcc000000),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is running on a phone Screenshot
[this is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfepY.jpg)
I don't know why there are white lines between children

Comment: on iOS simulator, it's not showing.

Comment: Have you tried this on real device? If so, try change the column's `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.start`. You don't need to center the column children because the column itself is already inside `Center` widget.

Comment: I tried to run the code on both of my real device `xiaomi` and `one plus`, and make `mainAxisAlignment ` to `MainAxisAlignment.start` ,They all have white lines

Answer (score 0):

This white line doesn't have to be there. The same code runs on two devices, one with only one, and the other with two
[image]

Comment: Instead of the code above, I changed the `MainAxisAlignment.center` to the `MainAxisAlignment.start`